# Explanation of heap shaping technique and how it is different from heap spraying

Tags: exploit, heap

Recent RDP [vulnerability](https://research.checkpoint.com/reverse-rdp-attack-code-execution-on-rdp-clients/) and exploits have mentioned the use of heap shaping technique. 
Can anyone please explain in details what is actually involved in using this tactic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap shaping (also called heap grooming, for a more passive approach) is the slightly more intelligent sibling of heap spraying while developing exploits. Therefore, to properly explain heap shaping one must first be familiar with [heap spraying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_spraying).

### heap spraying

Heap spraying is the act of intentionally filling (spraying) a target process's heap space with recurring/sequential data, using an external attack primitive.

Say for example, you've found a uninitialized-variable bug, where a variable is not initialized when it should, and is then used in a manner that could be dangerous depending on it's the actual value.

An example might make it clearer:

```
typedef struct __struct_cmd {
    int type;
    char shell_cmd[1024];
} struct_cmd;

void safe_cmd(struct_cmd* cmd)
{
    switch (cmd->type)
    {
    case CMD_1:
        strcpy(cmd->shell_cmd, SAFE_CMD1);
        break;
    case CMD_2:
        strcpy(cmd->shell_cmd, SAFE_CMD2);
        break;
    }
    system(cmd->shell_cmd);
}
```

In the above example, it's easy to notice that if a user provides any value other than `CMD_1` or `CMD_2` for `cmd.type`, `shell_cmd` will not be uninitialized and an unknown value will be passed on to the lucrative `system` call.

Being able to set `cmd->shell_cmd` to a specific value that is a valid (and malicious) shell command will potentially give us code execution on the target. Simply put, heap spraying is the act of getting a lot of heap memory space filled with the specific shell command we'd like to execute.

### heap shaping

Now that was a relatively trivial case, and quite frequently heap spraying/shaping are used to exploit memory corruption bugs but that's irrelevant. Usually, you'd be addressing many more constraints to successfully exploit a memory corruption, and "filling the heap with data" simply won't be enough.

Double-free and use-after-free bugs will require specific objects/structs be allocated at the same space  a different object previously reside in. You'd then need to make sure the heap has a specific *shape*, in a way, so that a different object will "fit" into a [coalescing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescing_(computer_science)) (or high fragmentation heap, as opposed to [low fragmentation heap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/low-fragmentation-heap)). You may need to make sure a specific instance you control through a primitive is allocated in the right spot. Getting the heap to be in that specific way is what's called "heap shaping"